# How to precompile all pages in NextJS dev mode?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I have a NextJS app with large pages. When I want to navigate to a new page in dev mode, next compiles it and then renders it. The issue is that this process can take up to 10 seconds. I've done prefetching with `useRouter`, but it's not making any difference.

Is there a way to pre-compile all the pages in dev mode?